# Different package names for a classes, generated by AXIS and CXF

Tags: wsdl, cxf, axis

I am trying to migrate from axis to cxf. Here's the problem i am facing: some packages has incorrect names being generated by cxf. Specifically there is a difference for a types, that located in xsd files, imported to main wsdl through `<s:import>` element: looks like cxf prefers xsd's file namespaces while axis not. This is gonna take much more time to migrate if i should change package names for all xsd types. Is it possible to ignore xsd namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

CXF's wsdl2java has a -pnamespace=package flag that can be used to map namespaces to non-default packages.